# How to remove a part of the string by positions using jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex, replace, textarea

I'm need to delete a part of the textarea value by caret positions... This value can be

```
### something
### another
###
```

so i want to remove the blank element "### ". because the remove action calls by the Enter pressed — so before adding "\n". and i can't use

```
.replace('### \n')
```

because there is no '\n', and without it, the JS will remove "### " in the first line.

i think, i must use regular expression, but i cannot find it :( i've tried to use something like this

```
$(h.textarea).val($(h.textarea).val().replace('/(\s{2,}\#{3})(\s+)/g', ''));
```

can you help me to find the correct expression?

Comment: How about `.replace('### $')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead

```
$('textarea').val($('textarea').val().replace(/(###)\s*$/g, ''));
```

You can check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/sbPGc/

Answer (score 0):

Try using .replace('^#{3}\s*$', '') instead. ^ matches line begining and $ matches line end.